# Only Partial Data Returned from Database Using JSP Form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I'm new to mysql and teaching myself the ropes.  I've come across a problem and hoping for some advice.

I created a form in a jsp page to insert data to a mysql database.  All data is properly inserted, and when I do select* all data is properly displayed in a table I created.  My problem is with my  update page.

When I call data from the database back into a form on my editdata.jsp page, only everything before a space is returned.  For example, I put the name 'Tom Jones' into a database, but when I go to retrieve it from the name field, only 'Tom' is returned; 'Jones' is not, but is still there in the database.

Here's my editdata.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action ="UpdateData" method ="post">
    <table border ="1" width="80%">


            <%ResultSet res = (ResultSet) request.getAttribute("EditData");%>
            <%if(res.next()){
                %>
                <tr>
                   <td>ID</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("id")%>>   
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Container Number </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=
<%=res.getString("containerNumber")%> ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Size </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("size")%>> 
 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Vessel </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("vessel")%>> 
 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Full Out Date </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=
 <%=res.getString("fullOut")%>> </td>
                </tr
                <tr>
                   <td>Empty In Date </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("emptyIn")%>
 ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Empty Out Date </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=
<%=res.getString("emptyOut")%>> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Full In Date </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("fullIn")%>> 
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Comments </td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="id" value=
<%=res.getString("comments")%>> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="update"> </td>
                </tr>

            <%}%>            
    </table>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And my EditRecord servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class EditRecord extends HttpServlet {

    Connection conn;
    ResultSet res;
    Statement stmt;
    String id, query;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  
    response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            id = request.getParameter("id");
            dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
            conn = dbconn.setConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            query = "select * from inventory where id = "+id;
            res = dbconn.getResult(query, conn);


        }catch(Exception e){



        }
        finally {
            request.setAttribute("EditData", res);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("editdata.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            out.close();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Again, the long and short of my problem is that full strings of data are not returned after spaces.  So 'TOM JONES' only returns 'TOM' to the form above for editing.  How do I get the full string of data to be returned.  I don't know if it matters, but I used VARCHAR for all my record info.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: this question is confusing. you have no "name" field in your form, but you mention it in your description multiple times. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Every field has name="id"? It is not proper.

Comment: Pennstatephil, I used the name as an example.  So my table has 8 columns, I recently added the id just to make my search easier as I work through this.  I have column named containerNumber and each value is 4 letters followed by 7 numbers.  So for example, ACSU 0000001.  Note the space between the letters and number.  So when I call this cell row in my edit function, the only thing that is returned is the letters, or ACSU in this case.  It is like that for every cell.  What I want to do is return the whole string of ACSU 0000001.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes inside HTML tags are separated by spaces.  That's why you're supposed to use quotes around the attribute values.

BAD:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("comments")%>>
```

GOOD:

```
<input type="text" name="comments" value="<%=res.getString("comments")%>" />
```